# Jupyter Notebook not printing table using tabulate

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a python script that works perfect on my Unix machine. In this script I'm printing several tables using tabulate. However, when I'm trying to use it to make a Jupyter notebook it executes fine but messes up with the tabulate output.
I've tried several different things like using different table formats such as 'HTML' but couldn't find any help anywhere.
Please help.
Here is a part of python code that I want to work the same in Jupyter notebook. 
For data file- `purchase_data.json`, please check [my github repo](https://github.com/ShikhaChm/Python_HeroesOfPymoli/tree/master)

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with open('purchase_data.json') as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print (" Heroes of Pymoli","\n")
print ("==================","\n")

# Total Number of Players
playersCount = df.groupby('SN')['Item ID'].nunique().count()
print ("**Total Number of Players**", "\n")
print (tabulate([[playersCount]], headers=['Total Players'], tablefmt='fancy_grid').encode('utf-8'))

#*Purchasing Analysis (Gender)** 
# * Purchase Count
# * Average Purchase Price
# * Total Purchase Value
# * normalized totals
genderPur = df.groupby('Gender').agg({'Price':['count','mean','sum']})
print ("\n**Analysis (Gender)**","\n")
print (tabulate(genderPur,
        headers=['Purchase Count', 'Average Purchase Price', 'Total Purchase Value'], 
        tablefmt='fancy_grid').encode('utf-8'),"\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out later so just thought my answer may be of help to someone else too. In my Jupyter notebook while Tabulate didn't work, **display** command worked. 
Example:-

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display

with open('purchase_data.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print (" Heroes of Pymoli","\n")
# Total Number of Players
playersCount = df.groupby('SN')['Item ID'].nunique().count()
print ("**Total Number of Players**")
display (playersCount)
```

For whole code click on [this link](https://github.com/ShikhaChm/Python_HeroesOfPymoli/blob/master/HeroesOfPymoli.ipynb).